# cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:plutus-core:happy:exe.happy

Tags: cabal, vscode, docker, macos

In the VS Code Docker Env setup on a Mac. I opened the starter project in the container. Ran cabal build in VS Terminal with devcontainer prompt.

```
Warning: Requested index-state 2021-08-14T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state ().
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: plutus-core:happy:exe.happy (dependency of plutus-core)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: plutus-core, plutus-core:happy:exe.happy)
```

After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: plutus-core,
plutus-core:happy:exe.happy

I get the same error with all the starter-pap commands

Answer (score 2):

The line `Falling back to older state ()` means you probably need to run `cabal update` first (which downloads a copy of the current hackage index state).

Comment: After running cabal update, cabal build was killed because a process used too much memory. I increased Docker memory to 3GB

Failed to build iohk-monitoring-0.2.0.0 (which is required by
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). The build
process was killed (i.e. SIGKILL). The typical reason for this is that there
is not enough memory available (e.g. the OS killed a process using lots of
memory).

Comment: You will need at least 8G of RAM (including swap).